# Is it possible to check if a column exists or not, inside a pyspark select dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON where some columns are sometimes not present in the structure. I'm trying to put a condition but it's giving an error.

My code is:

```
v_id_row = df.schema.simpleString().find('id:')

df1 = df.select ('name','age','city','email',when(v_id_row > 0,'id').otherwise(lit(""))
```

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: condition should be a Column
```

How can I do this validation?

Comment: You are mixing string and column usage in the select statement. If you add col for the field names should work, i.e col('name')

Comment: @abiratsis,when I did it in the way that the error suggested, it became: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

`df1 = df.select (col('name'),col('age'),col('city'),col('email'),when(col('v_id_row') > 0, col('id')).otherwise(lit(""))`

That works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
v_id_row = df.schema.simpleString().find('id:')

col_list = ['name','age','city','email']

if v_id_row > 0:
   col_list.append("id")


df1 = df.select(col_list)
```